# Could account abilities be based on total lifetime combined rep points rather than actual?

Tags: discussion

Being new to WP.SE, I had a question I really needed answering and put it up for bounty for 100 rep points.  This took me from 109 to 9.

Now, I don't have the reputation to up vote, down vote, or even comment so that I can interact with the users providing answers to my bounty question.

That's fine, and I'm sure I'm slipping through a crack here, but maybe some logic could be worked into the site that that allows people to continue to use what functionality they have earned in total on the site rather than that being specifically related to the number itself?

Comment: You can always comment in threads you started regardless of reputation.

Answer (score 8):

That wouldn't be fair. Bounties have a cost, and reducing your reputation as an early user shouldn't be taken lightly, otherwise everyone would do it for seemingly trivial questions. So there have to be consequences.

But lets say we implemented what you're asking. There would be other consequences. For example, what if you had earned thousands of reputation, but had never gone above 500 reputation because you used bounties at every opportunity? Such a user would never gain abilities granted at 1k and beyond despite earning enough reputation, because they spent it.

Alternatively, lets say all earnt reputation is cumulative and adds up to a final meta reputation that's used to grant privileges, then the above user now has access. However such a user is unlikely to be a practical and good member of the community by abusing bounties, and they've just been given powers reserved for trusted active members of the community, such as close voting and post editing. Now we might have a problem.

Such users do, and have, existed.

Back to your original issue, the solution is simply to participate in the site. Your questions can be up-voted, you can answer questions, all is not lost. As someone newer to WordPress you have ample opportunity for questions, and if you format them well and ask them clearly then things should start moving up in your reputation tab. If you need help writing good questions or want to check things, we're about to help